# TypeError: can't convert String into Integer when trying to enter authorization code for google drive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-drive-api

I am working with rails3. I am trying to integrate google drive api into my web application, for that, I took help from https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart having steps to quick start. By running code given on above link, prompt me for "Enter authorization code:" and when I Copy the given code after browsing to the link, and paste it into the prompt, gives error -

irb(main):001:0> load "quickstart.rb"

Enter authorization code: 4/-_vOHLDz41uMtZdUwX6hTMnU0cS5.kgigQXxSey4SgrKXntQAax1ih81ecwI

TypeError: can't convert String into Integer

I tried by taking code into single/double quotation but giving invalid authorization code.

Can anybody help me please.

Than You.

Comment: No need to quote the auth code, it's just a string and stays that way. The TypeError is from something else.Which version of the api client are you using? Is there a line #/stack trace for the error?

Comment: Ok, confirmed there was a bug introduced in the most recent version of the api client. Fix coming!

Answer (score 1):

0.4.5 of the API client has a bug which broke media upload, either upgrade to 0.4.6 or downgrade to 0.4.4